# Mysql Algorithm for great circle distance calculation

Tags: mysql, doctrine

I want to calculate distance between two zip codes before inserting the data to database .basically i have a these tables

**zip code table**

```
| zipcode |   lat   |  long  |

  01230     60.1756   23.12

  01240     60.1756   25.25
```

**customer table**

```
| name | zip code |

  foo    01230
```

**sales man table**

```
| name |  zip code  |  workingdistanceinkm

  foo     01240        200

  foo1    01230        100
```

What I want to do is calculate the distance between the sales mans  and the customer  if it is  any of the salesman working area before the data of the customer is inserted to customer table .

MY approach was to calculate the distance between a customer and every sales man that is  in the sales man table. But this makes a lot of queries for **example**  if I have 1000 sales man it means I am  calculating the distance between the new customer data to be inserted  with those every one of the 1000 salesmen.

I am wondering if it's possible to write one query to do the same task.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

www.zipcodeworld.com/samples/distance.php.html

note that distance calculations between zipcodes are not always the actual representations  of the distance. This is just the distance of an imaginary straight line between the two points. But in reality it is longer

Answer (score 0):

Below URL helped me a lot. Please check "Finding Locations with MySQL" section. Thanks.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3
```